# появление ошибки IndexError: list index out of range при попытке удалить эелемнты массива

Tags: python

На решение пришла следующая задача - "Учитель выписал на доску все числа от 1 до N (включительно) в ряд, после чего вышел из класса. Петя очень не любит числа, делящиеся на K. Поэтому он стер их с доски. Когда учитель зашел обратно в класс, он заметил, что чисел на доске стало меньше. Помогите ему выяснить, сколько чисел осталось на доске."

Взял числа на доске за массив, после чего заполнил его, но возникает ошибка при удалении элементов делящихся на K. За `N` взял `a`, за `K` взял `b`

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
arr = []

for i in range(a):
    arr.append(i+1)

for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
    if arr[i] % b == 0:
        arr.pop(i)
```

Comment: нельзя изменять массив по которому идет цикл в прямом направлении. Или идите по циклу с конца, или пишите в другой массив

Comment: `arr = list(range(1, a+1))`

Comment: `arr = list(range(1, a + 1))` - все таки нужен список, чтоб `pop` работал

Comment: @Zhihar да, я уже поправил

Comment: блин, постоянно про это спрашивают, а как пойдешь дубликат на закрытие искать, так ничего не находится

Answer (score 0):

у вас классическая ошибка -

вы модифицируете список (`arr.pop(i)`) одновременно по нему двигаясь, в результате у вас происходит следующее:

вы идете от `0` до `len(arr)` элемента, удаляя некоторые, в результате в определённый момент у вас становится меньше элементов, чем `len(arr)`, но вы пытаетесь к нему обратиться

правильным решением подобных задач было бы создание нового списка, в который просто не войдут элементы старого списка, кратные `b`